# How to run nox android emulator on RDP

Tags: android, android-emulator, remote-desktop

I am trying to run nox player via remote desktop but no luck till time,
here is what I tried, Installed nox on server running windows server 2008 r2 and setup rdp on it and give remote access to nodes on network and I made .rdp for nox palyer so I may be able to run it via rdp services, but when I run it on nude first it go fast till 75 then slow down till 90 and totally jamed with error saying due to unknwon reason nox is unable to run, but when I run it on server it runs prity fast and works good, my aim is to run an emulator over remote connection (RD) for android studio so I may be able to run it for android app tester.

Answer (score 1):

I use TeamViewer to connect to the remote computer and launch `Nox`. Then I logon with the native `Windows RDP` and use `Nox` without any issue.